# How can we find orphan jars in intellij idea project

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I have found useful tools to do this in eclipse like  Classpath Helper, but is there any plugin or way in intellij idea to find unused jar files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you know how to use the IDEA Dependency Analysis tool to find library dependencies, and while that could get you some of the way it's of course not enough.

The problem and fact is that there is no way of finding unused JARs by way of static analysis, since it is possible to refer to and create any class in any dependency by way of reflection/IoC/whatnot these days.

So, the best you can "hope" for is a tool that can tell which JARs are not explicitly referenced by your code - curiously that is absent from IDEA as far as I know (but I would love to be corrected on that point!)

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using maven and determining each module's dependencies manually. Classpath Helper is an astonishingly bad way to tell what jars you're using.

Comment: I know using maven is better approach but I was maintaining an old java project and I can't change it to maven project.